# Plot the 2D FFT of an image

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, fft

I'm trying to plot the 2D FFT of an image:

```
from scipy import fftpack, ndimage
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

image = ndimage.imread('image2.jpg', flatten=True)     # flatten=True gives a greyscale image
fft2 = fftpack.fft2(image)

plt.imshow(fft2)
plt.show()
```

But I get `TypeError: Image data can not convert to float`.

**How to plot the 2D FFT of an image?**

Comment: I know the physics ... the FFT of an image is complex, but symmetric about the origin. What is often displayed as an image is the power spectrum: the modulus-square of the complex transform. I don't know the `scipy` but I'd start by looking for "power spectrum" in the index. NB keep the transform if you want to invert it later, mod-square/PS is not invertable.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The result of any fft is generally composed of complex numbers. That is why you can't plot it this way. Depending on what you're looking for you can start with looking at the absolute value

```
plt.imshow(abs(fft2))
```

Comment: Thanks! Of course, I don't know why I forgot to take `abs(...)`... Sorry! Something else, this is the input : [image2.jpg](http://gget.it/ykp8jbsr/image2.jpg). Why is [the output](http://gget.it/gdcj01u4/figure_1-1.png) plain blue ? I can't see anything in the FFT output...

Comment: The scale is not good since you have few strong components (e.g. the 0,0 DC component). Try working in logarithmic scale `plt.imshow(np.log10(abs(fft2)))`

Comment: Solved with `plt.imshow(20*np.log10(abs(fft2)))`... This is now my first step in 2D FFT (after years working on audio 1D FFT + STFT)... :) 
Any idea how I could remove the horizontal lines of [this image](http://gget.it/ykp8jbsr/image2.jpg) by zeroing certain 2DFFT bins and then inverse FFT?

Comment: (This is my initial goal : remove the horizontal or nearly horizontal lines of a picture)

Comment: This is tricky. Nulling fft components may not work as you expect... I suggest you try on computer vision forums.

Comment: Ok @Anguy... I don't know any forum in this topic (of course search engine gives a lot...) do you know one?

Comment: There is one here at SO. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/computer-vision