# 2d Fourier Transforms: FFT vs Fourier Optics

Tags: python, scipy, fft

I am trying to use programming to increase my understanding of Fourier optics. I know that physically and mathematically the Fourier transform of a Fourier transform is inverted -> F{F{f(x)} = f(-x). I am having two problems <s>1) The second transform doesn't return anything like the original function except in the simple gaussian case (which makes it even more confusing), and</s> 2) there seems to be some scaling factor that requires me to "zoom in" and distort the transformed image to a point that it is much less helpful (as illustrated below). **Editted with suggestions from @Cris Luengo

[image]

```
#%% Playing with 2d Fouier Transform

import numpy as np
from scipy import fftpack
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import LightPipes

wavelength = 792*nm
size = 15*mm
N = 600
w0=3*mm

# Fields
sq = np.zeros([100,100])
sq[25:75, 25:75] = 1
F=Begin(size,wavelength,N)
I0 = Intensity(0,GaussBeam(F, w0, LG=True, n=0, m=0))
I1 = Intensity(0,GaussBeam(F, w0, LG=False, n=0, m=1))+Intensity(0,GaussBeam(F, w0, LG=False, n=1, m=0))

# Plot transforms
f = sq
F = np.fft.fftshift(fftpack.fft2(f))
F_F = fftpack.fft2((F))

plt.subplot(331), plt.imshow(f)
plt.title(r'f'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.subplot(332), plt.imshow(np.abs(F))
plt.title(r'F\{f\}'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.subplot(333), plt.imshow(np.abs(F_F))
plt.title('F\{F\{f\}\}'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])

# plt.subplot(331), plt.imshow(f)
# plt.title(r'f'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
# plt.subplot(332), plt.imshow(np.abs(F))
# plt.title(r'F\{f\}'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
# plt.subplot(333), plt.imshow(np.abs(F_F))
# plt.title('F\{F\{f\}\}'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])

f = I0
F = np.fft.fftshift(fftpack.fft2(f))
F_F = fftpack.fft2((F))

plt.subplot(334), plt.imshow(f)
plt.title(r'f'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.subplot(335), plt.imshow(np.abs(F))
plt.title(r'F\{f\}'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.subplot(336), plt.imshow(np.abs(F_F))
plt.title('F\{F\{f\}\}'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])

f = I1
F = fftpack.fft2(f)
F_F = fftpack.fft2(F)

plt.subplot(337), plt.imshow(f)
plt.title(r'f'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.subplot(338), plt.imshow(np.abs(F))
plt.title(r'F\{f\}'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.subplot(339), plt.imshow(np.abs(F_F))
plt.title('F\{F\{f\}\}'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: If you remove the calls to `fftshift` and `abs` things should work correctly. What are `I0` and `I1`? Do you need this much redundancy in your code to illustrate your problem?

Comment: @Cris Luengo Sorry I found an error in the demo I made for this and accidentally deleted my pic that shows what `I0` and `I1` are. I believe the `fftshift` is necessary for rearrange the quadrants correctly. Something about the standard is to put the high frequencies at the edge? and the `np.abs` is necessary because the result of `fft2` is complex.

Comment: I was trying to politely suggest that I had tried it without to begin with. The `abs` is there because of this issue. The correction for it was found here on stackoverflow `TypeError: Image data of dtype complex128 cannot be converted to float`

The shift comes from a youtube description of FFTs. After finding that when a small (10x10) square is used the intensities are at the corners which is wrong. They must be shifted.

Comment: @CrisLuengo here is the answer that motivated me to try adding the `np.abs` https://stackoverflow.com/a/38333442/14305494

Comment: `fftshift` is to shift the origin from the top-left (where the DFT/FFT expects it) to the center where we enjoy seeing it. Use it only when you want to display the result of an FFT. `abs` discards the phase of the DFT, destroying your data. It causes all sine components to be aligned at the origin, leading to the characteristic single peak in each of your results. `fft(fft(f))` will yield the result you expect. It will not exactly be `f(-x)` because we’re dealing with a discrete Fourier transform, not a normal FT.

Comment: Note that the answer you link is explicitly mentioning “plot”.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231282/discussion-between-charles-and-cris-luengo).

Comment: @CrisLuengo  I tried to start a chat as this suggests. I believe that I have made the edits you suggested, but this still does little to help with my intuition of Fouier transforms. a) the more real to life transforms are still not plotting reasonably, and b) I am now having to treat the second transform different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After chatting with Cris, it seems that there is no scaling factor, this type of DFT just works this way it seems. So the solution I have found is to increase the pixels to the point that I can zoom in and have a clear enough image. It's not a great solution but paired with `LightPipes` it is now possible to get an idea of what the transform of light modes will look like, as well as illustrate that at the image plane of a lens system they will appear as they did in the front focal field.

```
#%% Playing with 2d Fourier Transform

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import LightPipes
from scipy.fftpack import fft2 as fft
from numpy.fft import fftshift, ifftshift

wavelength = 792*nm
size = 100*mm
N = 1000
w0=3*mm

# Fields
sq = np.zeros([100,100])
sq[25:75, 25:75] = 1
F=Begin(size,wavelength,N)
I0 = Intensity(0,GaussBeam(F, w0, LG=True, n=0, m=0))
I1 = Intensity(0,GaussBeam(F, w0, LG=False, n=0, m=1))+Intensity(0,GaussBeam(F, w0, LG=False, n=1, m=0))

# Plot transforms
f = sq
F = fftshift(fft(ifftshift(f)))
F_F = fftshift(fft(ifftshift(F)))

plt.subplot(331), plt.imshow(f,cmap = cmap)
plt.title(r'f'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.subplot(332), plt.imshow(np.abs(F),cmap = cmap)
plt.title(r'F\{f\}'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.subplot(333), plt.imshow(np.abs(F_F),cmap = cmap)
plt.title('F\{F\{f\}\}'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])

f = I0
F = fftshift(fft(ifftshift(f)))
F_F = fftshift(fft(ifftshift(F)))

plt.subplot(334), plt.imshow(f[450:550,450:550],cmap = cmap)
plt.title(r'f'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.subplot(335), plt.imshow(np.abs(F)[450:550,450:550],cmap = cmap)
plt.title(r'F\{f\}'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.subplot(336), plt.imshow(np.abs(F_F)[450:550,450:550],cmap = cmap)
plt.title('F\{F\{f\}\}'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])

f = I1
F = fftshift(fft(ifftshift(f)))
F_F = fftshift(fft(ifftshift(F)))

plt.subplot(337), plt.imshow(f[450:550,450:550],cmap = cmap)
plt.title(r'f'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.subplot(338), plt.imshow(np.abs(F)[450:550,450:550],cmap = cmap)
plt.title(r'F\{f\}'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.subplot(339), plt.imshow(np.abs(F_F)[450:550,450:550],cmap = cmap)
plt.title('F\{F\{f\}\}'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]